# Mandatory Group / Autosubscribe in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, organic-groups, notifications

I'm using organic groups for a community website which notifies members when a new article is submitted to their group.

However I would like ALL members to receive notifications when the admins publish articles to the site.

There are 2 ideas on how I think this could be done:

1. Autosubscribe all users to receive notifications when articles are posted (to no group) by the admins
2. Have a 'General' group that all members automatically join on signup

I have seen a module for Drupal 6 which address idea 2 but so far I have not found any solution on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rules to do this (As OG7 uses rules for everything else).

1. Create new Rule
2. Add New Action
3. React on event: After saving new content
4. Add condition
5. Data Selector node:author
6. Choose whatever role is admin
7. Add Action
8. Send email to all users of role
9. Select whatever roles
10. Fill in your message with applicable tokens

You can also check out the [notifications and Messaging framework](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) or the new [Newsletter](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter) module for D7. These are better for allowing users to control which notifications they receive and can subscribe and unsubscribe themselves.

Comment: This solution worked but I had to also create another rule to auto-assign new users to a role for it to work.